# Launching Cpp app in javascript inside JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, javacpp

I have a JSP page which launches a CPP app. When an http request is sent from the CPP app, is there any way to get that request served in the JSP from which the app got launched?  Please advise

Comment: I guess that you want to run an executable. Try `java.lang.Runtime's exec() method`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for AJAX

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/